# Change URL format with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, hide

I've been trying to get a better URL format than the regular one. I have to deal with parameters, and I'd like to get from :

http://www.whatever.com/embed.php?site=site1&id=videoid

to :

http://www.whatever.com/embed/site/site1/id/videoid

I've been trying to get something like this using .htaccess, but I still don't understand how it really works.

This is what I have for now :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^embed/(.*)/(.*)$ /embed.php?site=$1&id=$2
```

The three first lines actually hide the .php extension, which is okay, but the next one doesn't work as I wish it would !

Any one as an idea ?

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^embed/site/([\w-]+)/id/([\w-]+)$ embed.php?site=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, the adress : http://www.example.com/embed/site/avalue/id/avalue doesn't show up correctly :(